# I can't load the library i created - Fatal error: Call to undefined function CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created the library file named Kategori.php but somehow i can't load library i created.

Here is the library code:

```
class Kategori {

public function panggil_kategori($id_jenis)
{
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $CI->load->model('ticketing_model');
     $idjenis = $CI->ticketing_model->getone_kategori($id_jenis);
     return $idjenis;

}
}
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public function browse_ticketing()
{
    $this->load->library('kategori');
    $this->data['data']=$this->ticketing_model->get_all();
    $this->data['body']='data_ticketing';
    $this->load->view('welcome_ticketing',$this->data);
}
```

Here is the view code:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-striped" border="1">
<h4>Open</h4>
<tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Judul</th>
    <th>Kategori</th>
    <th>Prioritas</th>
</tr>
<?php 
    $no = 1;    
    foreach($data as $row){
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['judul'] ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo panggil_kategori($row['id_jenis']); ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo $row['prioritas'] ?></td> 
</tr>

<?php
    }
?>
```

and here is the model code :

```
function getone_kategori($id_jenis)


{

$this->db->select('nama_jenis');
        $this->db->where('id_jenis', $id_jenis);

        $query = $this->db->get('jenis_user');
        return $query->row();
  }
```

When i try run my code the answer is Fatal error: Call to undefined function panggil_kategori() in C:\xampp\htdocs\helpdesk\application\views\data_ticketing.php on line 18..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`panggil_kategori()` is a method of class `Kategori`. You have to create an object of class Kategori in order to use it:

```
$myKategori = new Kategori();
```

Then

```
$value = $myKategori->panggil_kategori($id);
```

I can't see where you've instantiated a Kategori.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why are you using library for this operation, as you are just fetching the data fro m database then you can use some join conditions to get the records and pass to the view.

Well if you want to go with library then i recommend to use helper here as helpers are best suited with views.

Answer (score 0):

Your library is being loaded just fine.  The problem is in the view where you are trying to access a method in your library.  Its **bad practice** to be trying to access your library in the view.  I would suggest that you assign the return value of your method to a variable in your **controller** and then you can use it in your view.

So in your controller you want to do something like

```
$this->data['return'] = $this->kategori->panggil_kategori($value);
```

Then in your view you can do

```
<td><?php echo $return; ?></td>
```